# Разделение frontend и backend на nginx

Tags: yii2, nginx

Пытаюсь настроить конфиг на nginx. Задача сделать перенаправление на php когда в строке запроса появляется .../api/...

```
server {
    charset utf-8;
    client_max_body_size 128M;

    listen 80; ## listen for ipv4
    #listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on; ## listen for ipv6

    server_name sitename;
    root        /var/www/html/sitename/frontend/dist;
    index       index.html;

    access_log  /var/www/html/sitename/log/frontend/access.log;
    error_log   /var/www/html/sitename/log/frontend/error.log;

    location / {
        # Redirect everything that isn't a real file to index.php
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    # uncomment to avoid processing of calls to non-existing static files by Yii
    #location ~ \.(js|css|png|jpg|gif|swf|ico|pdf|mov|fla|zip|rar)$ {
    #    try_files $uri =404;
    #}
    #error_page 404 /404.html;

    # deny accessing php files for the /assets directory
    location ~ ^/assets/.*\.php$ {
        deny all;
    }

    location /api/ {
        root /var/www/html/sitename/backend/web;
        try_files $uri $uri/;
        index index.php;

        location ~ \.php$ {
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            #fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
            try_files $uri =404;
        }
    }

    location ~* /\. {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

Но при попытке сделать запрос выдается 500 Internal Server Error, что я делаю не правильно

Comment: Ошибка 500 возникает в коде php, ищите ее там.

Comment: В данном случае до php даже не доходит

Comment: Что заставляет вас так думать?

Comment: То что логи не пишутся, что какая-то ошибка произошла

Comment: Настройки nginx выглядят правильными. А описание сокета в www.conf совпадает с описанием в nginx?

Comment: Нет не совпадал. Затупил и забыл что поставил 7.1. Когда поменял ошибка исчезла, но теперь выдает 404 ошибку, хотя если прокинуть до api напрямую, то результат выдается

Comment: Логи nginx тоже читали?